# Where is Blender 3.01 SSGI?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I want to get SSGI to work in Eevee Blender 3.01 but I dont see the option
only Screen Space Reflections?
It was to my understanding that Screen Space Raytracing/ SSGI addon was coming built in
in Blender 3.0?

(Dont have 3.1 installed because certain models arent working properly in it)

Answer (score 0):

Blender 3.0+ doesn't yet have SSGI. It was not implemented, though it was announced.